# Must Riak save the entire map at once?

Tags: riak

I read that you can't append to a value in Riak. Does this extend to the Riak Datatypes that have been added? i.e. If i modify a register, counter, or flag in a map in Riak. Must it rewrite the *entire* map to the underlying value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rewrite all map/set.
see Examples http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.0.0/dev/using/data-types/#Usage-Examples

```
set = Riak::Crdt::Set.new(bucket, key, bucket_type)
cities_set.remove('Montreal')
cities_set.add('Hamilton')
cities_set.add('Ottawa')
```

Comment: Yes, but is riak forced to save the entire underlying map value back into the db? I read that a riak value cannot be appended to and I assume you can't insert into or modify the insides of a value either. You must write the whole value to the db again.

Comment: That's true for simple objects stored in buckets and found by key. CRDT's map/sets are a different beast.